# How many elements would have to be looked to locate these elements?

Tags: algorithms, searching

How many elements would have to be looked (binary search) at in order to find an integer 5000 at element 499 and an integer 7282 at element 686 assuming it's binary search algorithm and the total number of elements in the array are 1000? I do know that for the binary search algorithm you have divide the total number of elements that would be in your array(which is 1000) in half and keep doing until you find the desired element! Can someone help me? Please!

I do have a theory though (see my theory below:)

1000/2= the first element is 500 element

500/2 the next element is 250 element.

Comment: where are you having the trouble then, if you have an idea ?

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee i am not sure this right way to approach this problem.

Comment: so try it and find out ? or look at wikipedia etc.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Do you think you can help me? I am just not understanding. I know that 1000 elements would have 0-999 indexes for it, but the approach that I took doesn't make sense.

Comment: how do you keep stepping that's a start. how would you get to 499th index.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The approach that I took was the worst case scenario.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Do you think there are some online resources beside just Wikipedia that would show me how to solve my problem?

Comment: the only part you seem to not grasp is it doesn't necessarily just go down in the indexes.

Comment: @ Roddy MacPhee What do you mean?

Comment: @ Roddy MacPhee Halving the total number of elements which is 1000 would be a start right?

Comment: sure but you pick which way you go by what value is in the position as it's been sorted already before the algorithm starts.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee So if I divide 1000/2, I get 500th element but continually doing this won't help me find the 686 element.

Comment: correct because the other part is that it takes a certain 500 elements and if you pick the wrong one you will not ever hit the 686th of the original set. that's why comparisons to a target value happen.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee I am a visual learner and I need some sort of pictorial picture or examples. Do you think you can direct me or show what you actually mean? Please? I've been at this for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

here's a worked example of roughly how the algorithm works:

[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

I want to find 70:

I take the rough middle element ( which is 50) I compare it to 70 and:

if 50<70 I take roughly the upper half of the values
if 50>70 I take roughly the lower half of the values
if 50=70 I am finished

since 50<70 I take roughly the upper half of the values: [60,70,80,90,100] I then take the middle element (80) and compare that to 70 since 80>70 I take roughly the lower half of the values I took before:

[60,70,80]  I take the rough middle element ( 70) and compare it to 70 since 70=70 I am now finished.

Comment: I understand how you are approaching your own example, but my array is a huger than that! Would I have to create a java program in order to figure out how many elements or comparison would have to be gone through to find those two elements? Can this be done using pen and paper?

Comment: any element can be found in under $log_2(n)+1$ steps

Comment: Please read above the text I have written.

Comment: I did for your comment for 1 million elements the worse case scenario is about 20 comparisons.

Comment: So it can be done using an algorithm formula; So if I do logbase 2 of 1000 + 1, I will see the number of comparisons it would have to make? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: it should if you even understand my example.

Comment: Yeah stick to worse case because we know that best case won't help anyway!

Comment: here's the setup to find the 499th  take the 500th  if it's larger than the value  take the bottom half of the 1000 take the 250th of that subset compare it to the value wanted if it's less then take the top half of that subset, take the 125th element of that subset ( 375th in the whole ordered set) and compare it. if  it's less than the value you want take the values above it take the halfway point ( roughly element 437 in the original set) compare it if it's less then take the halfway point again 468th  of the original set roughly.After just 5 comparisons we're looking in the indexes 468-500

Comment: $log_2(n)+1$ is worst case @DMicheal at least in sets with a power of two number of elements.

Comment: @MacPheeSo it can be done with pencil and paper?

Comment: if you want to write out part of the data 10 times ( for 1000, 20 times for about 1 million) or so in theory.

Comment: you can also just map it as 500->250->375->437->468->484->492->496->498->499

Comment: the 686 case is 500->750->625->687->656->672->680->684->686

Comment: Never mind! I see now!

Comment: So to find the number of comparisons with 499 element it would be 9 comparisons and for 686 element, it would be 8 comparisons. You don't count the last one because it's the searchvalue you want, right?

Comment: you still have to compare it to make sure.

Comment: for the 1,000,000 case talked about before for 499,999 it works like this roughly  500,000->250,000->375,000->437,500-> 468,750-> 484,375-> 492,189-> 496,096->498,048->499,124->499,562->499,781->499,891->499,946->499,973->499,987->499,994->499,997->499,999